# Minimum per row in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array and want to calculate the minimum in each row:

```
import numpy as np

data=np.array([[ 9.052878e+07,  1.666794e+08,  9.783935e+07,  7.168723e+07],
       [ 1.033552e+04,  1.902951e+04,  1.117015e+04,  8.184407e+03],
       [ 1.000000e+15,  5.740625e+15,  3.419288e+15,  2.549149e+15],
       [ 1.000000e+15,  5.740625e+15,  3.419288e+15,  2.549149e+15]])

print(np.min(data))
#8184.407
```

`np.min(data)` claulates the total minimum and not row-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you

```
import numpy as np

data=np.array([[ 9.052878e+07,  1.666794e+08,  9.783935e+07,  7.168723e+07],
       [ 1.033552e+04,  1.902951e+04,  1.117015e+04,  8.184407e+03],
       [ 1.000000e+15,  5.740625e+15,  3.419288e+15,  2.549149e+15],
       [ 1.000000e+15,  5.740625e+15,  3.419288e+15,  2.549149e+15]])
np.amin(data, axis=-1)
# array([7.168723e+07, 8.184407e+03, 1.000000e+15, 1.000000e+15])
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want min for each row then mention axis - [np.min with axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html)

```
print(data.min(axis=1))
```